# Why do visitors look for old links in my webpage

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, shared

I recently migrated from a joomla webpage to a Laravel webpage, and i'm usign uniacid/visitors-log to log my visitors. The thing is that some visitors even after a week of totally removing the joomla site from public_html/ are logged as they visited por example:

```
templates/yoo_catalyst/css/menus.css
media/widgetkit/widgets/slideshow/styles/screen/img/
components/com_jdownloads/jdownloads.js
```

Which belong to joomla directories from the previous site.

Does this have to do with people having cached versions of the old website?

Comment: They're bots most likely.

Comment: As @Andrew said, it is likely bots. Could be some folks have bookmarked a few things too.

Comment: place `robots.txt` in your root

Comment: Try googling for your old pages. Maybe google (or some other search engines) are still finding your old pages (google cached them). If that's the case there are some google admin tools where you can "force" google to re-crawl your site and clear old cache.

Comment: There may also be broken links to your old pages, you should 301 redirect them to their equivalent new page. This will carry over any rankings those pages had in search engines too.